# Not a valid identifier while starting hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

When i start, writes that incorrect path to java

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hhfb.png

But I copied the path to java from IDEA

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYmqS.png

export

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X0tB.png

Comment: Consider editing your question to ask a question specific to your problem. Perhaps - How can the "not a valid identifier" error be corrected?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should not include the `bin` directory. Also, for future reference: do not post screenshots of textual information. Post it as code-formatted text.

Answer (score 2):

There's a space between the equals sign and the value in the `export JAVA_HOME` line in your hadoop-env.sh. Remove the space and it should work. `export` sets JAVA_HOME to empty and thinks the path is the name of another environment variable.

Also, are those quotation marks plain double quotes (`"`) or smart quotes? You should use plain double quotes (`"`) or single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Is `/Users/orestchukla/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_282/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java` an actual path? It doesn't look right. Also might I suggest that you should take some smaller steps to learn Unix before trying to run a Hadoop cluster?